# Can't unlocked Achievements in android

Tags: android

I am trying to build a game that has 5 achievements:
- Easy
- Normal
- Medium
- Hard
- Advance

But why I cannot unlock Achievement by code below:

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.achievement_easy));
```

But I can show all Achievement by using code below very well:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

and 
I can insert score into Leaderboard by using code below very well also:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_easy), inScore);
```

CatLog when trying to unlock Achievement:

```
08-08 14:47:33.513: W/dalvikvm(25551): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417fac08)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551): Process: kids.math.newmathforkids, PID: 25551
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kids.math.newmathforkids/kids.math.newmathforkids.update_score}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hn.a(Unknown Source)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.b(Unknown Source)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.AchievementsImpl.unlock(Unknown Source)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at kids.math.newmathforkids.update_score.onCreate(update_score.java:261)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-08 14:47:33.518: E/AndroidRuntime(25551):    ... 11 more
```

Activity:

```
public class Acs extends BaseGameActivity {
    protected static final int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 0;
    protected static final int REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score_update);

    TextView show_achievement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_achievement_level);
    show_achievement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
           }
        });

   String total_score_easy_level = s1.getText().toString();
   int score_easy = Integer.parseInt(total_score_easy_level);
   if(score_easy > 100)
        {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.achievement_easy));
        }
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("sigin failed", "inside on onSignInFailed");
}
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("sigin succeded", "inside on onSignInSucceeded");
    //subMitScore();
}
}
```

Anybody can help me on this problem?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error, I believe your google api client is not set properly. Make sure you follow [this guide from google's documentation step by step](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).

Comment: but I can insert score into leaderboard and show all achievement.

Comment: have you tried unlocking achievement rather than Oncreate maybe inside onSignInSucceeded or with a button after gamehelper is set?

Comment: There's a confusing mechanic in there.  Most methods that take a GoogleApiClient can be called before the client is connected, but there are a few that need to be called after the client connects.  Generally the write methods require a connected client, while read methods will just wait in a queue until the connection is made.  That being said, submitScore is a write method, and so it too requires a connected client.  Is there a chance that that is happening in a section where the client has connected, maybe because it's more than a couple seconds after the connect call?